# Update some fields in mongodb via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to build a simple restful API and I can't figure out how to properly update some fields in my mongodb via mongoose.

This is my Scheme:

```
   Sound = new Schema({
    "title"    : String,
    "url"     : String,
    "time"  : Number,
    "like"  : {
        "count": Number,
        "timestamps": [Number]
   }
}),

  Artist = new Schema({
    "author"            : String,
    "url_to_author_image"   : String,
    "bio"               : String,
    "sounds"             : [Sound]
});
```

I need to increment number of likes and add the timestamp to the array, when someone sends a request to /like/sound_id. So far, I have got something like this:

```
router.post("/like/:sound_id", function(req, res){
  var time = Date.now();

  Artist.findOneAndUpdate( {"sounds._id":req.params.sound_id},
  { $inc : { "sounds.$.like.count" : 1 } },
  { $push : { "sounds.$.like.timestamps": time } }, function(err,doc){
    if (!err) res.json({message: "wuuuuhuuu"});
  });
});
```

But the push part seems to be wrong.

Comment: What is happening to make you say it's wrong? Error? Exception? Field not updated?

Comment: I get a wuuuuhuuu message. Number of likes increments, but nothing happens in timestamps field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine both the `$inc` and `$push` into a single object as otherwise the `$push` is interpreted as the options parameter:

```
Artist.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "sounds._id": req.params.sound_id },
  { $inc : { "sounds.$.like.count" : 1 },
    $push : { "sounds.$.like.timestamps": time } },
  function(err,doc){
    if (!err) res.json({message: "wuuuuhuuu"});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working, although I am not sure, if it's the most effective solution.

```
Artist.find({"sounds._id":req.params.sound_id}, function(err, sound){
    sound[0].sounds.id(req.params.sound_id).like.count++;
    sound[0].sounds.id(req.params.sound_id).like.timestamps.push(time);
    sound[0].save(function(err){
      if (!err) res.send(200);
    });
  });
```